# very odd: a boolean value calculation in partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

The partial file:_link_topic_type.html.erb:

```
// debug info to check the passed in variables
<p>current_topic_type: <%= current_topic_type %></p>
<p>topic_type: <%= topic_type %></p>
<p>active: <%= current_topic_type == topic_type %></p>

<% if current_topic_type == topic_type %>
<li class="active">
<% else %>
<li>  
<% end %>

<%= link_to user.student? ? Topic::TOPIC_TYPES[topic_type] : '我的公告', 
            topics_path(user_id: user, course_id: course, topic_type: topic_type),
            class: 'topic-type-action' %>
</li>
```

And this file is called 4 times in action view template:

```
<% (1..4).each do |tt| %>
  <%= render partial: 'link_topic_type', 
                      locals: { user: user, course: course, current_topic_type: topic_type, topic_type: tt } %>
<% end %>
```

From the output, both of the 'current_topic_type' and 'topic_type' value are right, but the 'active' value is always false:

```
current_topic_type: 1
topic_type: 1
active: false

current_topic_type: 1
topic_type: 2
active: false

current_topic_type: 1
topic_type: 3
active: false


current_topic_type: 1
topic_type: 4
active: false
```

It is very odd. And i spent 2 hours on it and could not find any hint. Could anyone give some hint?

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing types? Could `current_topic_type` be a string and `topic_type` a number (or vice versa)? `topic_type` should be a `Fixnum` but what about `current_topic_type`?

Comment: You are right! It is because current_topic_type is parsed from http request params and is string type default. I converted it to int and it worked. Thanks very much!!!

Comment: An explicit `inspect` call (i.e. `<p>current_topic_type: <%= current_topic_type.inspect %></p>`) is useful when debugging, that will show differences that a plain `<%= ... %>` can hide.